# Why proGuard doesn't work when its active?

Tags: android, proguard, minify, android-r8

I want to reduce my app size.
I saw some tutorials and understood that I have to use the following code in build.gradle(app) :

```
buildTypes {
    release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

I tried it but the app size didn't change until I added another code and it worked :

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

**My question** is why it should be use debug because it wasn't used in tutorials I saw.

I'm worried about slow app with this way.

**Note :** My Android Studio version is 3.5 and my gradle version is 7.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Android Studio project default buildtype is debug, you can see it on "Build Variants" panel on left bottom corner of Android Studio. You can also change it to `release`

Comment: You can also build the release version on command line with `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`, then you don't have to switch Build Variants in Android Studio when you go back to debugging you app. Also read [Shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) carefully, as you might have to add additional keep rules if you use reflection in your application.